Условие дочерней таблицы через inner join не обрабатывается в запросе через @RawQuery. Room
Есть две таблицы: одна с общими данными (TaggingSpell) и данными локализации (Spell). Связываются они по uuid и по получаемой locale. Условия для общей таблицы обрабатываются, а для дочерней условие для locale игнорируется.
"select * from ${SpellEntity.TABLE_NAME} as t0 " +
"inner join ${TaggingSpellEntity.TABLE_NAME} as t1 " +
"on t0.${SpellEntity.COLUMN_UUID}=t1.${TaggingSpellEntity.COLUMN_UUID} " +
"and t0.${SpellEntity.COLUMN_LOCALE}='$locale' " 

Сам запрос рабочий, это явно проблема движка.
Посмотрел в дебагере на сгенеренный код, увидел строчку:
_stringBuilder.append("SELECT `uuid`,`name` FROM `spell` WHERE `uuid` IN (");
Полагаю это текст запроса, из которого достаются строки из второй таблицы, условия с locale - нет.
